# How do I get the find command to print out the file size with the file name?

Tags: unix, command-line, find, solaris

If I issue the [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)) command as follows:

```
find . -name *.ear
```

It prints out:

```
./dir1/dir2/earFile1.ear
./dir1/dir2/earFile2.ear
./dir1/dir3/earFile1.ear
```

I want to 'print' the name and the size to the command line:

```
./dir1/dir2/earFile1.ear  5000 KB
./dir1/dir2/earFile2.ear  5400 KB
./dir1/dir3/earFile1.ear  5400 KB
```

Answer (score 186, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.ear' -exec ls -lh "{}" \;
```

just the h extra from jer.drab.org's reply. saves time converting to MB mentally ;)

Comment: This version will exec "ls" process for each file. If you have many files (say, over a thousand) you better optimize that by either:  
`find . -name '*.ear' -exec ls -lh {} + \;` (GNU extension) 
or  
`find . -name '*.ear' -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lh`. Also you may like to add `-type f` if you're only interested in files (or add `-d` to ls if you want directories themselves included without their contents).

Comment: Your answer does not exclude directories, so you will end up running ls on directories as well, which clearly is not the right thing to do.

Comment: This is a really inefficient way of doing things - and unfortunately ash108's comments are also not ideal. It's much better to use the -printf option to find.

Comment: dmazzoni's answer is much more efficient because it avoids a fork+exec on every file (100x faster on my machine).  I had to change %k to %s.   @FaheemMitha: you can add options like `-type f` to only count regular files.

Comment: @FaheemMitha easy solution is `find . -name "*.ear" -type f` for files. `-type d` works for directories.

Comment: This also works: `find . -type f -name "*.bfc" -exec du -s {} \;`

Comment: This answer corners the output to only show Gigs or the original format. Also displays too much information. Op's examples only show file path and size. You can use the following to choose whatever size you want. `find . -name '*.ear' -exec ls -s --block-size=G {} \;` for gigs, and `find . -name '*.ear' -exec ls -s --block-size=M {} \;` for megs.

Answer (score 151):

You need to use -exec or -printf. Printf works like this:

```
find . -name *.ear -printf "%p %k KB\n"
```

-exec is more powerful and lets you execute arbitrary commands - so you could use a version of 'ls' or 'wc' to print out the filename along with other information. 'man find' will show you the available arguments to printf, which can do a lot more than just filesize.

[edit] -printf is not in the official POSIX standard, so check if it is supported on your version. However, most modern systems will use GNU find or a similarly extended version, so there is a good chance it will be implemented.

Comment: It looks like your example is more precise, but I can't seem to get the example to work on Solaris 10.

Comment: I'm afraid Solaris find does not support -printf at all:

http://jrwren.wrenfam.com/blog/2006/10/07/solaris-find-sucks/

http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~arik/usail/man/solaris/find.1.html

You could install GNU find if you can be bothered, otherwise you need to use exec or | as suggested by others.

Comment: +1 This seems more cleaner. To format the output I would prefer add `column` command. `find . -name *.ear -printf "%p %k KB\n" | column -t`

Comment: This answer is a much more correct way to do it than the accepted answer

Comment: The `-printf` option doesn't work in OS X either. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752818/find-lacks-the-option-printf-now-what.

Comment: Nit: the output lines up much nicer if you print the sizes first (while space-padding them): `"%010k KB %p\n"`

Comment: Moreover: the `%k` token is only capable of handling a 4KB (page size) granularity, rounded up. So, for example, if a file is only 3 bytes large it will appear as if it's 4 KB.

Answer (score 56):

A simple solution is to use the *-ls* option in *find*:

```
find . -name \*.ear -ls
```

That gives you each entry in the normal "ls -l" format. Or, to get the specific output you seem to be looking for, this:

```
find . -name \*.ear -printf "%p\t%k KB\n"
```

Which will give you the filename followed by the size in KB.

Comment: Didn't even know of an `ls` option, this should be far higher up in the list of answers than it is.

Answer (score 31):

Using GNU find, I think this is what you want.  It finds all real files and not directories (*-type f*), and for each one prints the filename (%p), a tab (\t), the size in kilobytes (%k), the suffix " KB", and then a newline (\n).

```
find . -type f -printf '%p\t%k KB\n'
```

If the *printf* command doesn't format things the way you want, you can use *[exec](https://linux.die.net/man/1/exec)*, followed by the command you want to execute on each file.  Use {} for the filename, and terminate the command with a semicolon (;).  On most shells, all three of those characters should be escaped with a backslash.

Here's a simple solution that finds and prints them out using "ls -lh", which will show you the size in human-readable form (*k* for kilobytes and *M* for megabytes):

```
find . -type f -exec ls -lh \{\} \;
```

As yet another alternative, "wc -c" will print the number of characters (bytes) in the file:

```
find . -type f -exec wc -c \{\} \;
```

Comment: +1 Except for having omitted `-name '*.ear'` in the examples, this should be the #1 answer. It answers the question precisely, explains the meaning of the syntax, and gives multiple alternatives.

Comment: this should be accepted answer as it doesn't run new command for every line, thus it is much more faster than the currently accepted one  from shyam

Comment: Indeed this should be the right answer.
Also, `find . -type f -printf '%k KB\t %p\n'` i.e., printing the file size first,  will most likely be a nicer output in terms of formatting due to the alignment.

Answer (score 9):

```
find . -name '*.ear' -exec du -h {} \;
```

This gives you the filesize only, instead of all the unnecessary stuff.

Comment: `wc` works for this just better, if you need the size in bytes.

Comment: *This gives you the filesize only,*  No, this gives disk usage, not file size. They are note the same. The value this returns will be wrong for any filesystem that supports compression.

Answer (score 7):

Just list the files (`-type f`) that match the pattern (`-name '*.ear`) using the disk-usage command (`du -h`) and sort the files by the human-readable file size (`sort -h`):

```
find . -type f -name '*.ear' -exec du -h {} \; | sort -h
```

Output

```
5.0k  ./dir1/dir2/earFile1.ear
5.4k  ./dir1/dir2/earFile2.ear
5.4k  ./dir1/dir3/earFile1.ear
```

Answer (score 4):

Awk can fix up the output to give just what the questioner asked for. On my Solaris 10 system, find -ls prints size in KB as the second field, so:

```
% find . -name '*.ear' -ls | awk '{print $2, $11}'
5400 ./dir1/dir2/earFile2.ear
5400 ./dir1/dir2/earFile3.ear
5400 ./dir1/dir2/earFile1.ear
```

Otherwise, use -exec ls -lh and pick out the size field from the output.
Again on Solaris 10:

```
% find . -name '*.ear' -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{print $5, $9}'
5.3M ./dir1/dir2/earFile2.ear
5.3M ./dir1/dir2/earFile3.ear
5.3M ./dir1/dir2/earFile1.ear
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following commands:

GNU `stat`:

```
find . -type f -name *.ear -exec stat -c "%n %s" {} ';'
```

BSD `stat`:

```
find . -type f -name *.ear -exec stat -f "%N %z" {} ';'
```

however `stat` isn't standard, so `du` or `wc` could be a better approach:

```
find . -type f -name *.ear -exec sh -c 'echo "{} $(wc -c < {})"' ';'
```

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this on Mac OS X where the find command doesn't support `-printf`.

A solution that I found, that admittedly relies on the 'group' for all files being 'staff' was...

```
ls -l -R | sed 's/\(.*\)staff *\([0-9]*\)..............\(.*\)/\2 \3/'
```

This splits the ls long output into three tokens

1. the stuff before the text 'staff'
2. the file size
3. the file name

And then outputs tokens 2 and 3, i.e. output is number of bytes and then filename

```
8071 sections.php
54681 services.php
37961 style.css
13260 thumb.php
70951 workshops.php
```

Comment: Useful to know.. The GNU version of `find` is available through homebrew with `brew install findutils`

Answer (score 3):

Why not use **du -a** ? E.g.

```
find . -name "*.ear" -exec du -a {} \;
```

Works on a Mac

Comment: Based on the [du man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html)
`
-a, --all
              write counts for all files, not just directories
`
I think you want to use -h 
`
-h, --human-readable
              print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
`

Comment: Because this prints disk usage, which is not the same as file size.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you what you're looking for, formatting included (i.e. file name first and size afterward):

```
find . -type f -iname "*.ear" -exec du -ah {} \; | awk '{print $2"\t", $1}'
```

sample output (where I used `-iname "*.php"` to get some result):

```
./plugins/bat/class.bat.inc.php  20K
./plugins/quotas/class.quotas.inc.php    8.0K
./plugins/dmraid/class.dmraid.inc.php    8.0K
./plugins/updatenotifier/class.updatenotifier.inc.php    4.0K
./index.php      4.0K
./config.php     12K
./includes/mb/class.hwsensors.inc.php    8.0K
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
find. -name *.ear -exec du {} \;
```

This will give you the size in bytes. But the du command also accepts the parameters -k for KB and -m for MB. It will give you an output like

```
5000  ./dir1/dir2/earFile1.ear
5400  ./dir1/dir2/earFile2.ear
5400  ./dir1/dir3/earFile1.ear
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*.ear" | xargs ls -sh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ find . -name "test*" -exec du -sh {} \;
4.0K    ./test1
0       ./test2
0       ./test3
0       ./test4
$
```

[Scripter World reference](http://www.scripterworld.com/2009/07/unix-find-command-with-examples-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*.ear" -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get total size, here is a script proposal

```
#!/bin/bash
totalSize=0

allSizes=`find . -type f -name *.ear -exec stat -c "%s" {} \;`

for fileSize in $allSizes; do
    totalSize=`echo "$(($totalSize+$fileSize))"`
done
echo "Total size is $totalSize bytes"
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try for loop:

```
for i in `find . -iname "*.ear"`; do ls -lh $i; done
```

Comment: it\s better to use the -exec argument in find - it\s made for exacly this purpose