# find lacks the option -printf, now what?

Tags: macos, find, printf

I have not found a reason why Mac's find does not have the option -printf.
Apple normally decides to take options out which are not orthogonal to the other commands?

**How can you reach the same result as the following command in Mac** without coreutils?

```
find . -printf "%i \n"         // command in Ubuntu
```

Comment: what is the expected output from the command?

Comment: Confused about why `%i` (inode number) was used as an example when `ls -Ri` would seem to be the preferred tool for the job there, and about the trailing space before the newline. Could the OP chime in on that?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It's not that Apple removes options, it's that OS X's UNIX underpinnings are mostly derived (circuitously) from FreeBSD, many parts of which can be traced back to the original UNIX... as opposed to the GNU utilities, which are re-implementations with many features added.

In this case, [FreeBSD's `find(1)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&section=1) doesn't support `-printf`, so I wouldn't expect OS X's to either.  Instead, this should work on a BSD-ish system:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f '%i '
```

It'll fail on a GNU-userland system, though, where you'd write `xargs -0 -r stat -c '%i '` because `xargs(1)` and `stat(1)` behavior is different.

Comment: For some reason this prints numbers instead of strings in iTerm2 on OS X 10.8.4. Instead, `gfind` from the `indutils` package of MacPorts suggested by dmckee works fine.

Comment: That's because %i prints the inode.

Comment: @TylerA. how to print file names instead of numbers?

Comment: @mesqueeb `man stat` gives you the different format values. it looks like replacing `%i` with `%N` will give you the file name, e.g. `find . -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f '%N '`

Comment: %N prints file full path, what if I only want file's basename?

Comment: @BruceSun you're either in [`basename`](https://man.openbsd.org/basename.1) territory, or you need to look into [Bash's parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), both of which are probably beyond the scope of this SO question.

Comment: something like `find ….. | xargs -0 [[[ bsd-stat -f '%N' or gnu-stat -c '%n' ]]] | gtr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 basename` ? yeah it feels like going in circles. Those square brackets mean nothing

Answer (score 49):

MacOS `find` binary does not support the `-printf` argument.

`gfind` supports `-printf` option, it can be installed using `brew install findutils`

Comment: This also works for FreeBSD and FreeBSD Jails. Thanks.

Comment: t h e_r e a l_m v p

Answer (score 23):

Well, [ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752818/why-does-macs-find-not-have-the-option-printf/752893#752893) and [bendin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752818/why-does-macs-find-not-have-the-option-printf/752905#752905) nailed the cause.

I'd add that there is nothing stopping you from installing GNU find (from the [findutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/findutils.html)) if you need it. If you use [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) there is a [`findutils` package](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/browse.php?summary=findutils). [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) has it [too](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/sysutils/findutils/Portfile).

Comment: You can install it with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) as well:

`brew install findutils`

Use `gfind` instead of `find` then.

Comment: @3zzy Does your path include the GNU version? Does it come before or after the system version? Using `gfind` may force using the GNU version.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you could just

```
find . -type f -exec stat -f "%z %N" {} \;
```

Granted, this isn't how you would do the same thing on linux, but works for MacOS

```
find . -type f -exec stat -c "%s %N" {} \;
```

produces similar (not same, but close) output on linux.

Comment: what's the `-type` and `-exec stat` stand for??

Comment: @mesqueeb  in a terminal type `man find`, then you'll be looking at a man page within the pager program called `less`; hit `/` to start a search, and search for those options. While searching, `n` advances to the next occurrence of the search term, while the capital `N` goes back to the previous occurrence.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu ships with the [GNU version of find](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/), which is more featureful than Mac OS X's find, which is of [BSD](http://www.bsd.org/) lineage.

In fact, most of the Ubuntu's user-land utilities are from the GNU project. (Thus you'll sometimes hear Linux-based systems referred to as "GNU/Linux".)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's worth noting that

```
ls -Ri | awk '{print $1}'
```

does effectively the same thing as the OP's example, on all platforms in question. I get that `-printf "%i \n"` may have just been a generic "for instance," though.

If you need a solution that is relatively certain to work in *both* GNU and BSD-ish environments, you can define a function which handles the underlying implementation details. However, this gets gnarly quick (as you'll see), and you have to start accounting for things like how to use `xargs -I{}` and still accommodate filenames with whitespace.

But if you're up for all that:

```bash
stat_inode_number() {
    if [ "$(uname -s)" = "Linux" ]; then
        # not sure if OP's trailing space was intentional, but keeping it here
        stat -c '%i ' "$@"
    else
        stat -f '%i ' "$@"
    fi
}

# export function to subshells, e.g., pipes
export -f stat_inode_number

find . -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 sh -c "stat_inode_number '{}'"
```

To briefly answer Bruce Sun's question [from above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752818/find-lacks-the-option-printf-now-what/752893#comment125494186_752893), of what to do if the existing `stat` formats don't suit your needs: you're either in [`basename`](https://man.openbsd.org/basename.1) territory at that point, or you need to look into [Bash parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) (*e.g.*, `${var##*/}`), both of which are beyond the scope here.