# How to echo directories containing matching file with Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, find, grep

I want to write a bash script which will use a list of all the directories containing specific files. I can use `find` to echo the path of each and every matching file. I only want to list the path to the directory containing at least one matching file.

For example, given the following directory structure:

```
dir1/
    matches1
    matches2
dir2/
    no-match
```

The command (looking for `'matches*'`) will only output the path to `dir1`.

As extra background, I'm using this to find each directory which contains a Java .class file.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.class' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u
```

From `man find`:

> `-printf` *format*
>
> `%h`     Leading directories of file’s name (all but the last element).  If the file name contains no slashes (since it is in the current directory) the `%h` specifier expands to `"."`.

Comment: Nice, thanks. For copy pasters: `find` also needs a directory after `find`, e.g. `find . -name '*.class' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u` to search from the current directory

Answer (score 35):

On **OS X** and **FreeBSD**, with a `find` that [lacks the `-printf` option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752818/why-does-macs-find-not-have-the-option-printf), this will work:

```
find . -name *.class -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 dirname | sort --unique
```

The `-n1` in `xargs` sets to 1 the maximum number of arguments taken from standard input for each invocation of `dirname`

Comment: On OSX, you can install gnu find with homebrew: `brew install findutils` and use it with: `gfind . -name '*.class' -printf '%h\n'`

Answer (score 7):

GNU find

```
find /root_path -type f -iname "*.class" -printf "%h\n" | sort -u
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i come way too late, but you also could do it without find, to answer specifically to "matching file with Bash" (or at least a POSIX shell).

```bash
ls */*.class | while read; do
  echo ${REPLY%/*}
done | sort -u
```

The `${VARNAME%/*}` will strip everything after the last `/` (if you wanted to strip everything after the first, it would have been `${VARNAME%%/*}`).

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
find / -name *.class -printf '%h\n' | sort --unique
```

Answer (score 1):

Far too late, but this might be helpful to future readers:
I personally find it more helpful to have the list of folders printed into a file, rather than to Terminal (on a Mac).
For that, you can simply output the paths to a file, e.g. folders.txt, by using:

`find . -name *.sql -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 dirname | sort --unique > folders.txt`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
find dirs/ -name '*.class' -exec dirname '{}' \; | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

For the `awk` command, see `#43` on this [list](https://catonmat.net/awk-one-liners-explained-part-two)

Comment: Wonderful! Not sure why no one earlier thought to use `find`'s `exec` command.