# How to recursively test all crates under a directory?

Tags: testing, rust, rust-cargo

Some projects include multiple crates, which makes it a hassle to run all tests manually in each.

Is there a convenient way to recursively run `cargo test` ?

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only one wishing to bundle multiple crates in the same repository. I am surprised cargo doesn't seem to have better support for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: since adding this answer 1.15 was released, adding `cargo test --all`, will compare this with a custom script.

---

This shell-script runs tests recursively on a git repository for all directories containing a `Cargo.toml` file (easy enough to edit for other VCS).

- Exits on the first error.
- Uses `nocapture` so stdout is shown
  *(depends on personal preference, easy to adjust)*.
- Runs tests with `RUST_BACKTRACE` set, for more useful output.
- Builds and runs in two separate steps
  *(workaround for [this bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37477) in 1.14 stable).*
- Optional `CARGO_BIN` environment variable to override the cargo command
  *(handy if you want to use a cargo-wrapper such as [cargo-out-of-source builder](https://github.com/ideasman42/cargo-oos)).*

Script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# exit on the first error, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/185900/432509
error() {
    local parent_lineno="$1"
    local message="$2"
    local code="${3:-1}"
    if [[ -n "$message" ]] ; then
        echo "Error on or near line ${parent_lineno}: ${message}; exiting with status ${code}"
    else
        echo "Error on or near line ${parent_lineno}; exiting with status ${code}"
    fi
    exit "${code}"
}
trap 'error ${LINENO}' ERR
# done with trap

# Support cargo command override.
if [[ -z $CARGO_BIN ]]; then
    CARGO_BIN=cargo
fi

# toplevel git repo
ROOT=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)

for cargo_dir in $(find "$ROOT" -name Cargo.toml -printf '%h\n'); do
    echo "Running tests in: $cargo_dir"
    pushd "$cargo_dir"
    RUST_BACKTRACE=0 $CARGO_BIN test --no-run
    RUST_BACKTRACE=1 $CARGO_BIN test -- --nocapture
    popd
done
```

*Thanks to @набиячлэвэли's answer, this is an expanded version.*

Answer (score 6):

You could use a shell script. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2282701/2851815), this

```
find . -name Cargo.toml -printf '%h\n'
```

Will print out the directories containing `Cargo.toml`, so, composing this with the rest of the standard shell utils yields us

```
for f in $(find . -name Cargo.toml -printf '%h\n' | sort -u); do
  pushd $f > /dev/null;
  cargo test;
  popd > /dev/null;
done
```

Which will iterate over all directories containing `Cargo.toml` (a good bet for crates) and run `cargo test` in them.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot test it right now, but I believe you can use `cargo test --all` to do that.

Comment: This option actually landed in stable Rust just today, in version 1.15!

Comment: Good things come to those who wait.

Comment: That has also been deprecated.  It served as an alias for the workspace flag.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the cargo workspace feature. [This crate](https://github.com/matthiasbeyer/imag) collection uses it in combination with a `Makefile`, which can be used to compile each crate on its own.

(The workspace feature helps to not compile common dependencies multiple times)