# How to recursively find and list the latest modified files, that end in*.html, in a directory with subdirectories and times?

Tags: find

building on this questiion and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7448828/2392358)

```
#!/bin/bash
find $1 -type f -exec stat --format '%Y :%y %n' "{}" \; | sort -nr | cut -d: -f2- | head
```

how do I alter this so that it searches for `*.html` files

Answer (score 0):

think thisis what I am looking for

```
find $1 -name '*.html' -type f -exec stat --format '%Y :%y %n' "{}" \; | sort -nr | cut -d: -f2- | head
```