# find: -printf: unknown option

Tags: macos, bash, shell, pipe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Mac's $find not have the option -printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752818/why-does-macs-find-not-have-the-option-printf)

Not sure what is wrong with the following command, but can anyone spot the error:

```
find public_html -name '*.php'  -printf '%h \n' | sort -u > dirlist.txt
```

Basically, I am attemtping to find out in my public_html directory names of all directories that have  *.php extension. and then print out the directory in which that file is found. The output of this is piped to sort, duplicate entries are removed by the -u flag, and the result is stored in new file dirlist.txt

But what I am getting upon execution is :

```
find: -printf: unknown option
```

Not sure where I am getting this wrong

Thanks

Comment: The error is because `find` doesn't *have* a `printf` option - exactly what the error message says. Check `man printf` on your system to figure out what to do.

Comment: Hi Adam, it's OS X Lion, using the mac terminal

Comment: You could install GNU findutils

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your version of find seems to have no -printf option.

I would do the same task like so:

```
find public_html -type f -name '*.php' | xargs -n1 dirname | sort -u > dirlist.txt
```

Comment: I guess this is because I am following a linux manual on a OS X terminal !

Comment: thanks all! the stackoverflow community is amazing, hopefully I am getting up to speed to start contributing as well !

Comment: @user1020069: I recommend updating your name.

Comment: @bukzor Similarly, do you know how to do the following without the -printf option (which I don't have)? --> find . -printf "%p (%s, %Tb %Td %TY %TH:%TM)\n" Basically I want the size and date/time to be listed as well.

Answer (score 1):

yes, your version does not seem to have -printf option - Mac variant doesnt i know - there may be others

your alternative is to pipe it to sed and sort, like so:

```
find public_html -name '*.php'|sed 's#\(.*\)/.*#\1#' |sort -u
```