# Difference between Mac `find` and Linux `find`

Tags: macos, shell, unix, find

I have inherited a script as part of a build process for an application, and when I run it on the build server (Ubuntu Precise) it runs fine, but when I run it on my mac I get "illegal option -- t". The command that has problems is simple, it's just a call to `find`:

```
find -type f -not -path [...]
```

On testing I have discovered that it is the `-type` option that has trouble on my Mac. If I run instead:

```
find ./ -type f -not -path [...]
```

It works, yet both work (seemingly equivalently) on the Linux box. Therefore my question is, are there significant differences between OSX's (BSD) `find` binary and the Linux (GNU?) `find` and will my modification to the script (adding the `./` path at the start) break anything that I haven't discovered yet?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752818/why-does-macs-find-not-have-the-option-printf

Comment: In Linux no need to mention the directory name or path .by default it will take the current directory.

Comment: In mac os specifying the path or directory mandotary fields

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) mandates the path (`./` in your example) to be mandatory.  `find` on MacOS follows the standard.

`GNU find` (the one available on Linux) allows the path to be optional.  If not specified, the current directory is assumed to be the path.  On Linux, man find says

```
find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [path...] [expression]
```

(note that path is specified within `[...]` denoting that it is optional.

It is a good practice to specify the path.

Comment: Ok thanks, I've updated the script to include the path, but I wasn't sure if I was missing some more fundamental syntax differences.

Comment: There may be other differences, but they'll mostly be differences in the options and tests they support -- for example, OS X's find supports `-Bmin`, `-Bnewer`, and `-Btime` tests that check the file creation date (inode "birth time"), which linux doesn't have; on the other hand, OS X's find doesn't support the `-D debugopts` option. But if the same find command runs without error on both it'll generally do the same thing on both...