# Find count of files matching a pattern in a directory in linux

Tags: regex, linux, bash, find, ls

I am new to linux. I have a directory in linux with approx 250,000 files
I need to find count of number of files matching a pattern.

I tried using following command :

```
ls -1 20061101-20131101_kh5x7tte9n_2010_* | wc -l
```

I got the following error message:

```
-bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
0
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 74):

It might be better to use `find` for this:

```
find . -name "pattern_*" -printf '.' | wc -m
```

In your specific case:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "20061101-20131101_kh5x7tte9n_2010_*" -printf '.' | wc -m
```

`find` will return a list of files matching the criteria. `-maxdepth 1` will make the search to be done just in the path, no subdirectories ([thanks Petesh!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143043/find-count-of-files-matching-a-pattern-in-a-directory-in-linux#comment31819991_21143109)). `-printf '.'` will print a dot for every match, so that names with new lines won't make `wc -m` break.

Then `wc -m` will indicate the number of characters which will match the number of files.

---

Performance comparation of two possible options:

Let's create 10 000 files with this pattern:

```
$ for i in {1..10000}; do touch 20061101-20131101_kh5x7tte9n_201_$i; done
```

And then compare the time it takes to get the result with `ls -1 ...` or `find ...`:

```
$ time find . -maxdepth 1 -name "20061101-20131101_kh5x7tte9n_201_*" | wc -m
10000

real    0m0.034s
user    0m0.017s
sys     0m0.021s

$ time ls -1 | grep 20061101-20131101_kh5x7tte9n_201 | wc -m
10000

real    0m0.254s
user    0m0.245s
sys     0m0.020s
```

`find` is x5 times faster! But if we use `ls -1f` ([thanks Petesh again!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143043/find-count-of-files-matching-a-pattern-in-a-directory-in-linux/21143109#comment31820609_21143109)), then `ls` is even faster than `find`:

```
$ time ls -1f | grep 20061101-20131101_kh5x7tte9n_201 | wc -m
10000

real    0m0.023s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.012s
```

Comment: to prevent recursing into subdirectories, you could use `-maxdepth 1` (if it's supported in that version of find)

Comment: ls has the bad habit of sorting before outputting, you should test with `ls -1 -f` to get a similar behaviour as find for performance evaluation

Comment: Pretty interesting, @Petesh, didn't know about it. I have tested the performance and to me with `ls -1f` it was even faster than `find`.

Comment: If you use the `-printf '.'` trick, you should count characters (`wc -m`) not lines. Alternatively, add a newline after the dot (`-printf '.\n'`).

Comment: How about using `--count` (`-c`) for `grep` and skipping `wc`? I would expect performance gain. (And also a simpler expression.) Then again, for the same reasons, I would expect `find` with `-name` to be faster than `ls|grep` while apparently it is not...

Comment: you should correct your answer to remove the wc -l everywhere and replace with wc -m

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann oh, good one. Updated, thanks. Feel free to [edit] if you find other things to improve.

Answer (score 6):

you got "argument too long" because shell expands your pattern to the list of files. 
try:

```
find  -maxdepth 1 -name '20061101-20131101_kh5x7tte9n_2010_*' |wc -l
```

please pay attention - pattern is enclosed in quotes to prevent shell expansion

Answer (score 5):

Just do:

```
find . -name "pattern_*" |wc -l
```

Answer (score 4):

## The MacOS / OS X command line solution

If you are attempting to do this in the command line on a Mac you will soon find out that `find` [does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/752893/338039) the `-printf` option.

To accomplish the same result as the solution proposed by [fedorqui-supports-monica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21143109/338039) try this:

```sh
find . -name "pattern_*" -exec stat -f "." {} \; | wc -l
```

This will find all files matching the pattern you entered, print a `.` for each of them in a newline, then finally count the number of lines and output that number.

[image: Using find to count matching filenames in MacOS and OS X]

To limit your search depth to the current directory, add `-maxdepth 1` to the command like so:

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "196288.*" -exec stat -f "." {} \; | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ls -1 | grep 20061101-20131101_kh5x7tte9n_2010_ | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

You should generally [avoid `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and in fact, performing the calculation in a shell function will avoid the "argument list too long" error because there is no `exec` boundary and so the `ARGV_MAX` limit doesn't come into play.

```
number_of_files () {
    if [ -e "$1" ]; then
        echo "$#"
    else
        echo 0
    fi
}
```

The conditional guards against the glob not being expanded at all (which is the default out of the box; in Bash, you can `shopt -s nullglob` to make wildcards which don't match any files get expanded into the empty string).

Try it:

```
number_of_files 20061101-20131101_kh5x7tte9n_2010_*
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all it is better not to use `ls` according to [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) article !!!**

and this problem can be solved in many ways. I will list some of the most elegant ones that come to my mind.

```
count=$(printf '%s\n' *pattern* | wc -l) 
#or
count=$(shopt -s nullglob; files=(*pattern*); echo ${#files[@]})
#or
count=$(file *pattern* | wc -l)
#or
count=$(stat -c "%n" *pattern* | wc -l)
#or
count=$(du -a *pattern* | wc -l)
#or
count=$(echo *pattern* | wc -w)
```

but last one gives the wrong number when the file names contain whitespace.

Comment: first version, `count=(*pattern*)`, will not work as expected if the pattern matches no file. In that case, `count` will be 1, not 0, because it will contain the pattern itself. `shopt -s nullglob` must be specified for it to work.

Answer (score -3):

```
ls -1 | grep '20061101-20131101_kh5x7tte9n_2010_*' | wc -l
```

Previous answer did not included quotes around search criteria neither * wildcard.

Comment: This is basically a repeat of a previous answer plus it won't work.

Comment: This is confusing shell wildcards and regular expressions. `grep` supports the latter, and will find a match on any substring, so the trailing wildcard is unnecessary, and also doesn't mean what you think. I support the idea that you should generally use quoting around your regexes, but in this particular case, it's not necessary, and the incorrect regex ruins the answer. For the record, the wildcard `*` (which mustn't be quoted) corresponds to the regex `.*`