# Using output from du, how can I display lines that correspond to files above or below a given size in bash?

Tags: linux, sorting, unix, du

I have du redirect into a file named stdout.txt, and the file's contents read as follows(for example):

```
4.0K    ./Makefile.am
20K     ./dfasearch.c
8.0K    ./dosbuf.c
4.0K    ./egrep.sh
84K     ./grep.c
4.0K    ./grep.h
8.0K    ./kwsearch.c
36K     ./kwset.c
4.0K    ./kwset.h
12K     ./pcresearch.c
4.0K    ./search.h
4.0K    ./searchutils.c
4.0K    ./system.h
```

From that file, I would like to be able to display only lines above or below a given size value.  "sort -h" gets me part of the way there, I think, but I'm not sure how to go about culling the lines I wouldn't need.  For instance, let's say I only wanted to print lines that represented a 12K or less file, my output should look something like:

```
4.0K    ./Makefile.am
8.0K    ./dosbuf.c
4.0K    ./egrep.sh
4.0K    ./grep.h
8.0K    ./kwsearch.c
4.0K    ./kwset.h
12K     ./pcresearch.c
4.0K    ./search.h
4.0K    ./searchutils.c
4.0K    ./system.h
```

Is there a common tool that naturally sorts by human-readable sizes and displays only the lines below (in this case) a given size?  Ideally, I'd like to have some bash code that could be used to generate this output above or below a user-provided number that could be denoted by K, MB, or GB, etc.

Comment: You can use the `find` tool to find files over a certain size and pass this file list to `ls` (or `du` if you insist) instead. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/64699/421705

Comment: That's pretty good, thanks.

Comment: On second glance, it's still not quite what I'm looking for, I misunderstood your response and thought you meant 'find' could look inside my file.

Comment: What I mean was, use something like `find . -type f -size -12k -exec du -h {} \;` This command gathers all the files which are smaller than 12K and only passes those to `du`.

Comment: I see that, and thanks again, but I am reliant on the intermediate file because I have more going on in my script than I could fit into this question.

Comment: Save yourself a ton of trouble and drop `-h` from `du`. It's much easier to format for humans at the end when you don't have to process it anymore.

Comment: Hmmm...it looks like I might have to.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort` with option `-h` (at least with `sort` from the GNU coreutils version 8.25).  With this option it sorts human-readable numbers like you have them here with suffixes `k`, `M`, etc. or without a suffix.

After sorting it is just a question of finding the place where to cut.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd advise you is to drop the `-h`, just use `du -k`. Once this is done, you might refer to `awk` just to see the entries, being larger than your desired value, as explained in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987512/how-to-extract-only-values-greater-than-a-threshold-from-a-file), hereby an example:

```
du -k . | sort -n | awk '{if($1>1000000) print $1 $2}'
```