# use Ls -l in script shell linux and separate between results

Tags: linux, bash, shell, typescript, ls

when i execute this script that i had made

```
#!/bin/bash
for object in $(ls -l)
do
echo $object
done
```

it's displayed as below
[image: ls -l script KO]

when i execute my script i want to have a result like this
[image: ls -l script OK]

i was trying a lot of things but its not working
please i need your help
thank you in advance

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: [How do I get the find command to print out the file size with the file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64649/608639), [Sort the output of find -exec ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140561/56041), [How to use the exec option in find with examples](https://linuxaria.com/howto/linux-shell-how-to-use-the-exec-option-in-find-with-examples), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You want to read the output of `ls -l` line by line; to do this, replace the line

```
for object in $(ls -l)
```

by

```
ls -l|while read object
```

and change

```
echo $object
```

to

```
echo "$object"
```

(to preserve spaces).

---

If you insist on using `for`, you can do:

```
readarray -t < <(ls -l)
for object in "${MAPFILE[@]}"; do echo "$object"; done
```

Comment: do you have any suggestions please?

Comment: @rim the thing is that you don't want to parse `ls` at all. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093846/use-ls-l-in-script-shell-linux-and-separate-between-results/48093940#comment83162204_48093846).

Comment: @PesaThe i want that ls -a list all the objects (file,folder..) of my current directory and seperate between file.... like in the picture.

Comment: what @Armali write is correct and working as i want , but with "while boucle ", and me i want " For boucle".thank you for your suggestions

Comment: @rim - For me to be able to suggest anything further, you'd have to clarify: Why do you want `for` instead of `while`? Is there anything you can't accomplish with `while`? What is `boucle`? If you need anything else than the result shown in your question, you should edit the question.