# Display the Files and Folder details under a parent directory in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, ls

I have to display all files and folders details under a parent directory.
I am using the command is 'find'. For example,

```
find /usr/local

/usr/local/bin
```

It's display only the file name. I have to display file name with details about files like below. Means I have to add below information in the above result set.

```
-rw-rw-- 1 hduser hduser 213 jan 22 11:51
```

How to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the find command to print out the file size with the file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64649/608639), [find -exec with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119946/find-exec-with-multiple-commands), etc.

Answer (score 3):

There's the convenient action `-ls`:

```
find /usr/local -ls
```

If you need some other than the default `-ls` output format, the action `-printf` is appropriate; with that you can freely define the format, e. g.:

```
find /usr/local -printf "%i,%k,%M,%n,%u,%g,%s,%t,%p\n"
```

Cf. [`man find`: Print File Information](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Print-File-Information).

Comment: I'm using 'find /usr/local -ls' 

It's showing like below.

19799045      4 drwxr-xr-x   9 hduser   root         4096 Feb 23 11:00 /usr/local

I have to do the comma seperated like below.
19799045,4,drwxr-xr-x,9,hduser,root,4096,Feb 23 11:00,/usr/local
How to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below command to list it nicely in a order and block wise:-

```
find . -type d |xargs ls -ltr
```

For your case:-

```
find /usr/local -type d |xargs ls -ltr
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `sudo find /usr/local -name "filename" -depth -exec ls -ll {} \;`

Comment: Why making it too complex. See the answer by [Armali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48947137/7975442)

Comment: I don't see this complexity, if you see, probably you need study more... And this SIMPLE command can be extended do various and useful things, like delete all *.pyc files for example, `find /path/to/folder -name "*.pyc" -depth -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: Yes your command can be extended to do various useful things, but that doesn't fits as a `SIMPLE` answer to OP. BY the way, I didn't downvoted your answer.

Comment: I still can't see where is this complexity that you talking about, I only introduce 2 more params.